# VB.Net convert Excel file to PDF: error at ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: excel, vb.net

ERROR MESSAGE: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'

I narrowed down my problem but I still get an error:
I have a loop that opens up each excel file from a location and then saves it as PDF.  It works and it creates a number of PDFs and then errors out at the ExportAsFixedFormat line.  The number of PDFs files that get created varies, therefore I would not think there is a problem with the Excel file.

Also, I added DoEvents and Wait(hopefully in the right spots) but I still get the error.

I also noticed that after I get the error I move the debugger back a few lines and run again the ExportAsFixedFormat and it runs fine. It creates that PDF and continues to produce more.

Please help as I have been trying to find a solution for days.
This is the code I have now:

```
'OPEN XLSX DOC TO SAVE AS PDF
Dim xl As Object
xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim xwb As Object
Dim workBooks = xl.Workbooks


System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()


xwb = workBooks.Open("\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesExcel\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " 050720.xlsx")

xwb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False
xwb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
xwb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False


NewDate = DateAndTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)
Do Until DateAndTime.Now > NewDate
     Application.DoEvents()
Loop


Dim newHour = Hour(Now())
Dim newMinute = Minute(Now())
Dim newSecond = Second(Now()) + 10
Dim waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
xl.Wait(waitTime)


'SAVE AS PDF
xwb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, "\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesPDF\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " " & todaysDate & ".pdf")


xwb.Close()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xwb)
xwb = Nothing
workBooks.Close()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBooks)
workBooks = Nothing
xl.Quit()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xl)
xl = Nothing
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: You might consider telling us the error message.  Based on your description, I suspect that it is "Call was rejected by callee.", but we should not have to guess when you can tell us error.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` is almost always the wrong thing to do - please see [Use of Application.DoEvents()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/1115360).

Comment: Hi, sorry, the error message is:   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'